# EXCEL: Number of days since last visit

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am trying to calculate the number of days since a specific person last visited a location.

Looking at the following sample dataset, what would be the best method?

[image: Sample dataset screenshot]

I tried making an index column and used vlookup to return the index then do a simple subtraction, but vlookup is limited to returning the first instance of the name and not the latest one.

Thanks

EDIT: My trouble isn't with finding the number of days between two dates, I am having trouble identifying where date A is located in the dataset, i.e. the last time this particular person visited. If I can find date A (last date visited), I can subtract it from date B (current visit date).

EDIT 2: Thank you for the answers everyone. Each was helpful in increasing my knowledge. Thanks for highlighting the inclusion of desired results in the question, will remember that next time.

Comment: Spoiler alert: go look up `datedif`.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks for the input but my trouble isn't with finding the number of days between two dates, the trouble is identifying where date A is located in the dataset, i.e. the last time this particular person visited. If I can find date A, I can easily subtract from date B. What do you suggest I combine datedif with to reach that objective?

Comment: Try using '=MAXIFS(A2:A6,B2:B6,B2)' to obtain the maximum value, then do the required calculations.

Comment: @raafsid, considering your issue, you have uploaded insufficient data,, I think your data should have Columns like,, NAME, Visit 1, Visit 2, Visit 3 and then finding nth occurrence of the visit is looking viable,, and so find the DAYS between nth occurrence and Current date, please [edit] your post and load some meaningful data!!

Comment: Hey @raafsid,, now check my post I've solve the problem. ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method? Depends on what you want for results, which you did not illustrate in your question

If you

- want the table filled out as you show,
- and by `DAYS SINCE LAST VISIT`  you mean the number of days between `today` and the most recent vist,

then, assuming your dates in the DATE column are "real Excel Dates" and not merely text strings:

(Using a Table and Structured References, which you can change to regular addressing if you prefer):

---

`=TODAY()-MAX(([NAME]=[@NAME])*[DATE])`

[image]

**algorithm**

- compare NAME on formula row with all NAME's
- This returns an array where if they MATCH, return TRUE, else FALSE
- Multiply each by the DATE.

  - Those with TRUE will return the actual date, else `0`
- Result is an array of all the dates that match the name
- Subtract the MAX of the matching dates from TODAY()
- You can replace `TODAY()` with any other date for comparison.

  - *If you do this, I suggest you either use a specific cell where you've entered the date, or, if you are hard-coding it into the formula, use the `DATE` function so as to avoid ambiguity due to Windows Regional Settings.*
- If those dates are NOT real dates, and merely text strings; and if the MDY order is the same as your window regional short-date settings, then, to convert them to real dates first, you can use:

  ```
   =TODAY()-MAX(([NAME]=[@NAME])*SUBSTITUTE([DATE]," ","-"))
  ```

***If you mean something else, please be more specific*** and provide an example.

**NOTE:**
One of the issues is that you have not clarified what you want for results.

The screen shot below shows several potential outcomes, in addition to what I showed above with formulas.  The larger table was generated using Power Query.

Other results are feasible, but you need to decide what you really want, in detail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Ensure that your date is actually stored as a date. Column C in the screenshot converts your space-separated date parts into a date

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))
```

The calculation for last visit is "Filter all the dates for this person that are before the date on the current row. Then get the max of that list of dates. If there is an error, it means there are no other dates, so return blank"

```
=IFERROR(MAX(FILTER($C$2:$C$6,($B$2:$B$6=B2)*($C$2:$C$6<$C2))),"")
```

The calculation for days since last visit is just the last visit minus the date on the current row.

```
=IF(D2<>"",C2-D2,"")
```

You can of course combine all of this into a single formula.

Answer (score 0):

*Using helper column & few array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

- Below shown method finds number of days since last visit, *from any number of visits*.
- In below used sample database Alex has 4 visits, therefore the difference of days should be counted *between vist4 & visit3.*

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- For helper value the formula in cell J2:

  `=I2&COUNTIF($I$2:$I2,I2)`

**N.B.** *This makes the job easier to find person's visit.*

- Ar array (CSE) formula in cell K2:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$10, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K$1:K1, $I$2:$I$10), 0)),"")}
  ```
- To find the last visit date an array (CSE) formula in cell L2:

  ```
  {=IF(MAX(IF($I$2:$I$10=K2,$H$2:$H$10))=0,"",MAX(IF($I$2:$I$10=K2,$H$2:$H$10)))}
  ```
- Now the final array (CSE) formula in cell M2:

  ```
  {=IF(IF(L2<>"",L2-LARGE((($H$2:$H$10)*(--($I$2:$I$10=K2))),2))=0,"",(IF(L2<>"",L2-LARGE((($H$2:$H$10)*(--($I$2:$I$10=K2))),2),"")))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Date format is `mm/dd/yy`
- Finish array (CSE) formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- While using the function `LARGE` with formula in cell M2, always put the **K** th value in correct order.

  `=LARGE((($H$2:$H$10)*(--($I$2:$I$10=K2))),2)`
- Where **k**th value `1` finds the LATEST date, in used data set for ALEX the LATEST date is `06/02/2020`, **k** th value `2` finds second
  LATEST date i.e. `05/05/20` and so for others.

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*